# How to know whether jsp field values or changed or not in Struts2?

Tags: jquery, struts2

Am using struts2 in our application,i have two pages and when am moving forward/previous am storing in the DB.When user moves from first page to second then he came previous page and if user clicks on the next button i will update the db with the values.In this scenario is there any client side script or any function to identify whether user has modified any field in the first page.In my page i have text field,radio buttion,checkbox,date picker.

Answer (score 1):

Your question can be interpreted into different use cases, here are some possible ways to address the issue.

You can use the token interceptor / token tag to generate a unique token per page. Your action can check if this token has been submitted previously and take appropriate action (this will require managing the tokens in your application).

When the back button is pressed you can create a ajax service to check if the token has been used. In this way when the back button is pressed ajax will call the action and be able to identify that it has been used and then warn the user.

Going further down the client side route, you could use client side storage to save the state of the form before submitting, when the back button is pressed the client side storage will be checked and will confirm that the page has been submitted. With the appropriate JS you can identify the values that changed between the previous and current submission and do what you want.